# Google earth Plugin with (preferable) Java

Tags: java, google-earth-plugin

I wish to build an application that utilize google-earth-plugin with Java (preferable) My goa, in a nutshell, is to use the plugin with the 3D images and to allow endusers to navigate to areas that I defined in advance and add some other features.

My understanding is that GE API has deprecated and developers should use the GE plugin. If so, what is the preferable language to build a GE applications. I'm comfortable with Java (on eclipse); but I couldn't find any '101 tutorial' that explains how to create a simple 'hello world' (not sure this is doable at all).

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java Wrapper for GE-API. It is a pretty advanced project with already 3rd stable version of the code. I personally never used it. Maybe someone can comment how good it is.
Here is the link:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-earth-3/

Anyways, you can use GWT to write Java projects that incorporate usage of JavaScript.
Here is the link:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/overview

Good Luck. These days almost any architectural solution is possible. Don't listen to people that tell you that you can't do something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use Java and GE API, you should embed a GE plugin enabled browser in your Java application and I haven't found such browser. And I don't know how to embed a browser in a Java App

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the GE Plugin a little while now but I've been using the C# plugin.  It is fairly easy to work with but knowing javascript would make it much easier (I don't).

The plugin has a javascript interface so if, as Paco said, you can find a way to embed a browser in your app and send it javascript commands you should be fine.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try an answer but I do not know Java!!

You can embed the plugin in a QWebView . And maybe Qt Jambi is done for you, java user
http://qt-jambi.org/

hope this can help :-/