# Java application with Google earth

Tags: java, netbeans, google-earth

i am here to ask if it is possible to open and control google earth using a java application. I'm developing a Incident Record Management System for a police station, i am thinking on adding a feature that would show the user where incidents have occured using google earth. Is it possible for a java application to do that. I am using NetBeans to develop this project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281689/google-earth-plugin-with-preferable-java

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the google maps API. It's faster than google earth, has been used more so there are more supportive articles about it.

Check it out: https://developers.google.com/maps/